# Using TextBoxFor to edit time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I´m trying to use TextBoxFor to display a input element to edit the time (Hour and Minutes) of a DateTime property.

In my model, the property is configured as follow:

```
public DateTime Hour { get; set; }
```

In my view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hora, "HH:mm", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

but always it display full date and time values, like:

```
11/25/2015 13:40:00
```

And I need only:

```
13:40
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use EditorFor instead of TextBoxFor and use data annotations in your model or viewModel, like this:

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime Hour { get; set; }
```

And then in your view you use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Hour, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

You can offcourse use the format you want for the string. In the link below you will find a complete reference:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: It does not display the time. It only displays "--:--". I need to include the attribute: [DataType(DataType.Time)].

Comment: Indeed it was only displaying "--:--". I'm sorry but I could not test it before. I've edited the answer so you can pre populate its value (either from the controller or the view, it's up you). But offcourse if you don't pre populate it, it will always show "--:--".

Comment: Even doing all this right, it generates an input like this:  <input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required field." id="Hour" name="Hour" type="time" value="01/01/2000 09:30:00">. That´s  the reason to display "--:--", the value should be only "09:30".

Comment: Could someone explain why this only shows AM / PM format to me? I already tryied changing the locale in Web.config and global.Asax, it keeps showing AM/PM, my PC time is set to 24 hrs.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the [jQuery.DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/) with relative success.

In your view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Hora, new { @class = "form-control" })

<script>
    jQuery('#Hora').datetimepicker({
        datepicker:false,
        format:'H:i'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using a auxiliary property in my class that maps DateTime to a string, already formatted.

In model:

```
    private DateTime hour;
    [Required]
    public DateTime Hour  //this is my mapped property
    {
        get
        {
            return hour;
        }
        set
        {
            hour = value;
            //update unmapped property 
            hourString = value.ToString("HH:mm");
        }
    }

    private string hourString;
    [NotMapped]
    public string HourString {
        get
        {
            return hourString;
        }
        set
        {
            hour = new DateTime(hour.Year, hour.Month, hour.Day, Convert.ToInt16(value.Substring(0, 2)), Convert.ToInt16(value.Substring(3, 2)), 0);
        }
    }
```